# setLocale in Auth::routes()

Tags: php, laravel, localization, multilingual

I want to create multilanguages website but I have a problem with Auth::routes(). Look at this code:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'pl'], function(){
    App::setLocale('pl');
    Auth::routes();

});
Route::group(['prefix' => 'en'], function(){
    App::setLocale('en');
    Auth::routes();

});
```

Alweys Login wwebsite is in english language or polish, if I will change the order. How I can solve my problem?

Comment: you can make it like this would be better `['prefix' => App::getLocale()]`

Comment: No, becouse url address will be translate too